# how to Windows Remote Desktop to Linux Mint using xrdp?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, linux-mint

I am in the process of migrating from Windows to Linux. This will take some time because I am a newbie Linux user. In the meantime I would like to be able to access Mint with Windows Remote Desktop (RDP). That should be possible with [`xrdp`](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=154150). When I connect with RDP to the Linux machine a window opens. It remains open for 6 seconds, showing a grey window, and the window disappears. The log file reads:

```
[20161228-15:20:48] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 1358
[20161228-15:20:48] [INFO ] listening...
[20161228-15:25:13] [INFO ] shutting down sesman 1
[20161228-15:26:14] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 1416
[20161228-15:26:14] [INFO ] listening...    [20161228-16:31:55] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20161228-16:31:55] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username arnold, ip 192.168.178.3:1474 - socket: 7
[20161228-16:31:55] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20161228-16:31:55] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=4459 - wmpid=4458
[20161228-16:32:01] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username arnold, display :10.0, session_pid 4455, ip 192.168.178.3:1474 - socket: 7
```

I do not know why the session terminated, did not touch the keyboard or the mouse. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use VNC?

Comment: I am now working on xrdp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, which I found in [this article](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5382), is to create a .xsession file with `mate-session` in it, e.g.

```
echo mate-session> ~/.xsession
```

The article also mentions methods to reconnect to a "lost session". Interesting enough that automatically happens in my setup. If that does not happen with your setup you can try one of the three suggestions mentioned in the article.